# Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I have tried various suggestions on solving the above error but its still there. Below is my repository. How can I solve this?

```
@Transaction
public interface ApplicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Application, BigInteger> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update application set transaction_status = :transaction_status where id =:id")
    void updateStatus(@Param("transaction_status") int transaction_status, @Param("id") BigInteger id);
}
```

Comment: Please add  @Transactional annotation to the function. Or decorate your service class with this annotation if this is a part of a transaction which contains more than one DML.

Comment: Not the class! The method must be Transactional

Comment: There is no any other function.

Comment: I tried changing interface to @Transactional not working aswel

Comment: share the complete stack trace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given your `ApplicationRepository`, I am assuming that you are using Spring JPA.

The exception you are facing to is `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException`.

You have already added `@Transactional` annotation to the repository, but please make sure that the import which you are using for is **`org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`**, because it seems that you might be using `javax.transaction.Transactional`.

I also suggest to you to use `@Transactional` on the class/method of the repository consumer.

Comment: if using multiple datasources then do not forget to provide the transactionManager as shown below

Comment: if using multiple datasources, then add the transactionManager as shown below  @Repository
@Transactional("transactionManager4entstg")
public interface MDHNativeQueryRepo extends JpaRepository<StgCip900Kna1, String>

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for, thank you so much!. BTW, I also applied your suggestion of using the annotation on the consumer methods, but I have a doubt: Should I remove the annotation from the repository methods?

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional instead of @Transaction you have made @Transaction this is the issues